# .appendTo Makes text overflow outside of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on something were i need to append text from a div to another div, this is fine and i have done this, the only problem is that when the div is moved, it will then make the text overflow as if there is no width (just one big long string of text overflowing out of the div) the div is still keeping its width.

```
   <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
   $(".item-content").appendTo(".tp-fade");
   });
   </script>
```

The Code above, moved below to a div with a class of .tp-fade

```
   <div class="item-content">
   Lorem ipsum...
   </div>
```

But when it does move the text seems to ignore the `<div>`s width.

EDIT:

Apologies. It was just a stupid mistake on my part. Turns out the `.tp-fade` has a sneaky `white-space: nowrap` hidden away and when i removed it; the fixed the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: please share jsfiddle of it.

Comment: No problem, just working on it now.